# Remove GNOME and install dwm

Tags: gnome, dwm

I'm currently running Fedora 19 on my PC and I want to remove GNOME and then use dwm. Is it enough when I install dwm and remove GNOME completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to remove GNOME to use dwm, you can just install dwm and use it instead.

Removing GNOME *might* simplify cirvumventing xdm/gdm (dm = display manager; these are the things that control the graphical login) -- but it also might not.  If you install multiple DEs, they may configure the dm to use a chooser, however, a stand-alone window manager such as dwm won't be included.

Meaning, you have to do a bit of manual work to run dwm anyway, so I recommend you just leave GNOME on disk.  To use dwm you will want to create a `~/.Xclients`:

```
#!/bin/sh

dwm
```

Make that executable: `chmod o+x .Xclients` (I'm not sure if that is really necessary).  If either that or `~/.xinitrc` already exists, edit that instead and comment out whatever is there (i.e. add `#` to the beginning of the line), and put `dwm` at the bottom.

At this point, you should be able to try dwm by logging out and switching to an unused VT (e.g. via `ctrl-alt-F3`).  Log in on the console and type `startx`.

You can then try rebooting to see if xdm will use your configuration.  If not, you need to disable the xdm or gdm services.  I don't have those installed, so I am not sure what systemd calls them -- `systemctl list-units | grep dm` should provide a clue.  Then `systemctl disable [whatever]`.  You'll need root or sudo to use the systemctl commands.  Then reboot.  You will probably end up at a console prompt, just log in and type `startx`.